# the isomorphism between two matrix groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, group-isomorphism, ring-isomorphism

is there any isomorphism between two $n{\times} n$ matrix groups with inverse? If yes, what the isomorphism function?.

I have read that  the $n{\times}n$ group matrix or $GL(n,\Bbb C)$ is isomorphic tothe group matrix $GL(2n,\Bbb R)$. Is this true ?

Comment: It's not even true for $n=1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).